# custom Progress Dialog in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I follow the steps in the [customdialog example](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) in the documentation, but I get this exception. Any ideas?

```
04-03 18:50:28.787: VERBOSE/Bru_Press_Tab(750): Exception in Tabsjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brown/com.example.brown.Bru_Press_MostRecent}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely, you are calling `requestWindowFeature()` after calling `setContentView()`. It may be you are not doing that directly, but that classes you inherit from are, because you are doing some other things slightly out of sequence.

So, find out where you are doing that and change the order such that you call `requestWindowFeature()` first.

For example, [here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/08-Threads/LunchList/) from one of my books that uses the progress-indicator-in-the-title-bar trick and therefore needs to call `requestWindowFeature()`. I had to do that in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()` on the activity.

Comment: how do we customized ProgressDialog box having customized background and customized buttons (positive and cancel)? Please steer to example code I need it badly.