# Custom Progress Dialog Android

Tags: android, android-widget, progressdialog

I have followed following links to customize the progress dialog :

[How to center progress indicator in ProgressDialog easily (when no title/text passed along)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225889/how-to-center-progress-indicator-in-progressdialog-easily-when-no-title-text-pa)

[custom Progress Dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571361/custom-progress-dialog-in-android)

I want to create custom progress dialog like in this image [image] but that code does not show a progress dialog in my application.Please guide me how to do this ? Also guide me how can i change the color of progress dialog according to my projects theme ?

Comment: do u also plan to change position of ProgressDialog?

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 7):

I have done this way:

Use this class for **Custom Progress Dialog**:

```
public class CustomProgressbar extends Dialog {
    private static CustomProgressbar mCustomProgressbar;
    private CustomProgressbar mProgressbar;
    private OnDismissListener mOnDissmissListener;

    private CustomProgressbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progressbar);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }

    public CustomProgressbar(Context context, Boolean instance) {
        super(context);
        mProgressbar = new CustomProgressbar(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mOnDissmissListener != null) {
            mOnDissmissListener.onDismiss(this);
        }
    }

    public static void showProgressBar(Context context, boolean cancelable) {
        showProgressBar(context, cancelable, null);
    }

    public static void showProgressBar(Context context, boolean cancelable, String message) {
        if (mCustomProgressbar != null && mCustomProgressbar.isShowing()) {
            mCustomProgressbar.cancel();
        }
        mCustomProgressbar = new CustomProgressbar(context);
        mCustomProgressbar.setCancelable(cancelable);
        mCustomProgressbar.show();

    }

    public static void showProgressBar(Context context, OnDismissListener listener) {

        if (mCustomProgressbar != null && mCustomProgressbar.isShowing()) {
            mCustomProgressbar.cancel();
        }
        mCustomProgressbar = new CustomProgressbar(context);
        mCustomProgressbar.setListener(listener);
        mCustomProgressbar.setCancelable(Boolean.TRUE);
        mCustomProgressbar.show();
    }

    public static void hideProgressBar() {
        if (mCustomProgressbar != null) {
            mCustomProgressbar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void setListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
        mOnDissmissListener = listener;

    }

    public static void showListViewBottomProgressBar(View view) {
        if (mCustomProgressbar != null) {
            mCustomProgressbar.dismiss();
        }

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public static void hideListViewBottomProgressBar(View view) {
        if (mCustomProgressbar != null) {
            mCustomProgressbar.dismiss();
        }

        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showProgress(Context context, boolean cancelable, String message) {

        if (mProgressbar != null && mProgressbar.isShowing()) {
            mProgressbar.cancel();
        }
        mProgressbar.setCancelable(cancelable);
        mProgressbar.show();
    }

}
```

**dialog_progressbar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_progressbar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add **drawable** file named with **bg_progressbar.xml** in **drawable** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#7F000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Now whenever you want to **start Progress** Dialog, just write **1** line code:

```
CustomProgressbar.showProgressBar(MainActivity.this, false);
```

Whenever you want to **dismiss Progress** Dialog, just write **1** line 
code:

```
CustomProgressbar.hideProgressBar();
```

Hope this will help you.