# Where i can found library like MBProgressHUD for ios, but for android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

For iOS i use MBProgressHUD for show progress indicator and i love it.

For android i use standart progress dialog, but i want to create some beautiful progressbar with spinner like in ios.

I want loading image like this [image: ios spinner]

If you have any information about it, please answer.

Sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: There he is https://github.com/anupamdhanuka/AndroidProgressHUD

Comment: There is an excellent answer on this by volkilam here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14996762/1502020

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way with a ProgressDialog:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainSite.this, null, "Loading.... Please Wait...");
```

Declaration at android developer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

And an example:
http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/showing-progressdialog-in-android-activity/

Comment: I founf this Thread. It should helps you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295001/custom-progress-dialog-android